# Sending emails by mailer model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a database created using Ruby-on-Rails.  What I require is a model (perhaps) where I can input some information in a form and then press a button that sends emails to all the users registered in the database.  The email contains the details written in the form.  Is that possible?  Any help will be very appreciated.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Yes... gather the email addresses in the database. Use the native mailing class for the server technology you are working with. Build the message body as a string (if its a simple email, otherwise you'll want to populate a template file). Create a mail message for whatever server technology you're working with and send to all the gathered emails with the generated body.

Answer (score 0):

Yes yes yes! Rails delivers some great support when it comes to sending emails! using Mailers (you can generate these) all you would need to do is set it up, I would also advice using a gem like mailchimp to test the sent data.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html 
this tutorial should help you out alot!

Also use your Terminal to fire the Mailers this will make ur process so much faster.

```
rails console or script/console
```

rails 2:

```
MailerClass.deliver_mailer_subclass(passed_parameters)
```

rails 3:

```
MailerClass.mailer_subclass(passed_parameters).deliver
```

Have fun